# Returning a char** dynamic array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, char, return

I basically have a dynamic char array that stores names and have declared it as `char **names`.

I have a variable called `namesnumber` which is used to set the size of the `names` array.

For example,

```
namesnumbers = 5
names = new char*[namesnumbers];
for (int i=0; i<namesnumbers; i++)
{
   names[i] = new char[65];
   strcpy(names[i], actualName);
}
names = {Mike, Sam, Mark, Bill, George}
```

This is my return method, however it only returns a memory address and not the actual namess

```
const char** getNames()
{
   return names;
}
```

I want my `getNames()` method to return the 5 names.

Comment: Use std::string and std::vector or std::array.

Comment: Why are you using C-style strings and memory allocation in a C++ program ? Use std::string and std::vector and save yourself a lot of grief.

Comment: You have the address to the place where the names are stored, you have to dereference it to get the names

Comment: @MauricioTrajano How would I go about doing that? Sorry, I am new to C++ and I am willing to learn

Comment: you can dereference it buy index, say if char ** names_returned = getNames(); Then names_returned[0] gives the first name, names_returned[1] gives the second, and so on... Although I only come from a C background and not a C++ one I do suggest you use std::string to avoid complications

Comment: If you're new to C++, I suggest you check [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), as well as [a good reference site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp).

Comment: `Sorry, I am new to C++ and I am willing to learn ` As others have pointed out, this is an excellent moment to learn about `std::vector` and `std::string`. Please please please make use of them for your own sanity.

Comment: Please help me, I just want to know how pointer arrays work. I will use `std::vector` and `std::string` next time

Comment: Your code example doesn't compile, please correct this.

Comment: Please show more about your actual task! Currently you're talking in a very confuse way about technical terms you don't understand. Help us help you. (-1 so far)

Answer (score 2):

```
// namesnumbers = 5
names = new char*[namesnumbers];
for (int i=0; i<namesnumbers; i++)
{
   names[i] = new char[65];
   strcpy(names[i], actualName);
}
// names = {Mike, Sam, Mark, Bill, George}
```

Equivalent initialization using std library:

- separate from instantiation:

  ```
  std::vector<std::string> names;
  for(const auto& n: actualNames) // actualNames assumed to be an array
      names.push_back(n);
  ```
- at instantiation:

  ```
  std::vector<std::string> names = { "Mike", "Sam", "Mark", "Bill", "George" };
  ```
- returning the five names:

  ```
  const std::vector<std::string>& getNames()
  {
      return names;
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks, what about for not using a vector? Just dereferencing the array?

Comment: @RewsProg You can't dereference an array. Arrays are not pointers. Pointers are not arrays.

Comment: What are you seeing in the code snippet you quote at the beginning of your answer? I see a mess that doesn't even compile, regardless of any scope you may try to build around. So, your *Equivalent initialization using* must be an error. (sorry: -1)

Comment: @Wolf, it was obvious the point of the question was not if `namesnumbers = 5` is missing a semicolon at the end and is not declared. I didn't bother with that.

Comment: @utnapistim Sure, but why do you quote this nonsense as a reference?

Comment: @utnapistim much better now thanks (-1 rem). Maybe a short statement about the wrong syntax would be good. (BTW: this still doesn't compile and the actualName in the loop is still a problem). And, last but no least: great that you took the burden to help in this *very difficult* case :-)